# GroupBy and First in MongoDb query

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregate, distinct

[Solved in comments]

I'm trying to get only distinct languages out of a table with objects that all contain a language and language code in MongoDB.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
public async Task<List<TranslationObject>> ListAvailableLanguages()
    {
        return await _collection.Find(x => 
                x.CountryCode != null &&
                x.CountryName != null)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

Afterwards I retrieve unique languages from said list by running this piece of code:

```
foreach (var translation in translations.DistinctBy(x => x.CountryCode))
        {
            languages.Add(new Language()
            {
                Code = translation.CountryCode,
                Name = translation.CountryName
            });
        }
```

As you can probably tell, this is not a very ideal way of doing this. I'm looking to apply the distinct operation (or GroupBy rather, as I want distinct CountryCode and CountryName combo) on the database call itself, however, I'm not that good at MongoDB calls. I tried using aggregate but I'm not sure how to, as the google searches I did on it didn't exactly match my needs.

Input needed for call: None.

Actual output: A list of all Translationobjects where CountryCode and CountryName is not null, meaning a ton of translations with duplicate CountryCode and CountryName.

Ideal output: A list of unique language objects with CountryName and CountryCode strings, but only the first instance of each is needed.

Comment: please add sample input data and your expected output to get more helps

Comment: There is no input, it's a GET rest API call. The data exists in the database and I want every single unique CountryCode and CountryName combination in the database. The database itself is constructed up of one translationObject with lots of meta data about the translation, including the content of the translation itself, and all I really want is the CountryCode and CountryName from said objects.

Comment: Use Distinct instead Find

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't think I can accept answer when it's comment like this, but this is it ^